# Trying to style Nav links in modal menu differently from Navlink in full screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

i am trying to apply a style for my nav items when in modal menu because the inital full screen styling is interfering with the smaller screen, ive tried media queries but it isnt working, the initial nevbar list styling can be found in the list component while the nav items in modal menu can be found in the index component of the navbar folder

this is code from the list component that keeps interfering

```
 import { SelectedPage } from "@/shared/types";
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"

interface Props  {
    page: string;
    selectedPage: SelectedPage;
    setSelectedPage: (value: SelectedPage) => void;
}

const Link = ({page,selectedPage, setSelectedPage}: Props) => {
    const lowerCasePage = page.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "") as SelectedPage;
  return (
   <AnchorLink
   className={`${selectedPage === lowerCasePage ? "text-primary-100" : ""}
   transition duration-500 hover:text-primary-300`}
   href={`#${lowerCasePage}`}
   onClick={() => setSelectedPage(lowerCasePage)}> 
    {page}
   </AnchorLink>
  )
}

export default Link
```

code from index component of the navbar as follows

```
import { SelectedPage } from "@/shared/types";
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"

interface Props  {
    page: string;
    selectedPage: SelectedPage;
    setSelectedPage: (value: SelectedPage) => void;
}

const Link = ({page,selectedPage, setSelectedPage}: Props) => {
    const lowerCasePage = page.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "") as SelectedPage;
  return (
   <AnchorLink
   className={`${selectedPage === lowerCasePage ? "text-primary-100" : ""}
   transition duration-500 hover:text-primary-300`}
   href={`#${lowerCasePage}`}
   onClick={() => setSelectedPage(lowerCasePage)}> 
    {page}
   </AnchorLink>
  )
}

export default Link
```

i tried media queries that didnt work, however i created a different component "ModalList" though it worked i am trying to come up with a solution with less code